# Can I use a faucet for my application

Tags: blockchain, gas, faucets

I am implementing the blockchain into the web app to track user's work with one another and plan to have tokens within the smart contract to exchange with one another. The user who deploys the contract will have all the tokens initially and will give other users a base amount of tokens on signup.

Is it correct or even possible to solely depend on faucets for eth to pay for the gas fees to transfer these tokens to other users or is there another way?

Sorry if I used incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on third party faucets probably work for a test environment.

It is not a good approach for an app in production. Either each user obtain ether to pay for gas, or you provide a faucet to your users.